# "Connection refused" trying to connect to Heroku DB from one computer, but not the other, same network

Tags: macos, sockets, networking, tcp, port

I opened up a new account with Heroku and installed the dev Postgresql add-on.  I'm using a 2010 Mac Pro with OSX 10.8.5 with firewall disabled, directly connected to my RCN/Cisco cable modem, and I installed Postgresql 9.3 on my local machine from http://postgresapp.com/.  I could connect to the Heroku postgresql fine from a Macbook Air, but not the Macbook Pro.  So from both machines, I tested connecting to port 5432 with telnet.  Connects fine on the Macbook Air, but not the Mac Pro.  I can browse the web fine from both machines, and also connect to a telnet site (one I had available) on port 4000 on both.

I get this error:

```
Trying 54.235.194.252...
telnet: connect to address 54.235.194.252: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Using Wireshark, I tried viewing the tcp packets on port 5432 when trying to telnet.  Just the Connection refused, and nothing showed up on the packet log.  But I saw plenty when telnetting on port 4000.

Other things I tried on the Mac Pro:

- I did an `nslookup ec2-54-235-194-252.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
  and it returns `54.235.194.252` as expected.
- traceroute on the IP address gives a `No route to host` and mtr shows
  nothing too.
- `sudo ipfw list` shows `65535 allow ip from any to any`, which is the same as the Macbook Air
- tcpdump and Wireshark for that host on the active interface showed nothing when telneting.  Seems to have gotten dumped even before getting to the interface.

I then tried running the telnet command through dtruss and saw this:

```
write_nocancel(0x1, "Trying 54.235.194.252...\n\0", 0x19)        = 25 0
socket(0x2, 0x1, 0x6)        = 3 0
getuid(0x2, 0x1, 0x0)        = 0 0
setuid(0x0, 0x1, 0x0)        = 0 0
setsockopt(0x3, 0x0, 0x3)        = 0 0
connect(0x3, 0x7F8F20C0DAD0, 0x10)       = -1 Err#61
write_nocancel(0x2, "telnet: \0", 0x8)       = 8 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "connect to address 54.235.194.252\0", 0x21)         = 33 0
write_nocancel(0x2, ": \0", 0x2)         = 2 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "Connection refused\n\0", 0x13)      = 19 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "telnet: \0", 0x8)       = 8 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "Unable to connect to remote host\0", 0x20)      = 32 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "\n\0", 0x1)         = 1 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
```

Err#61 is the BSD error code for ECONNREFUSED, which makes sense.  I think the socket options is setting the IP "Type of Service", but I'm not sure.  It looks like setsockopt has 5 arguments, but I only see three.  I have a feeling it's not relevant.  I have no idea what could be getting in the way other than ipfw and the firewall in System Preferences.  I also tried with the newly installed postgresql running and not running.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong with my Mac Pro.  Discovered you could safe boot in OSX... hold down "Shift" after the startup tone, then let go when you see the gray apple icon.  Could connect no problem in safe mode.  Noticed another game I was running via Wine, Subspace/Continuum, also started working.  So I compared the "ps aux" in safe and normal mode.  A couple of lines, only in normal mode, referred to a program, "Peer Guardian" that was silently blocking random ports from being used.  Looked up and realized there was a tiny "PG" mixed in with other symbols on my menu bar, just waiting to make me feel embarrassed.  Had to uninstall it using a tool I got off CNET called "AppDelete".  Ugh.